# AHK keystroke bind to keystroke

Tags: autohotkey

I want alt+s to trigger win+s (search functionality in windows 10). So I have

```
!s::#s
```

But the keystrokes don't map to eachother. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

To do what you ask, you should use:
`!s::send #s`

Your configuration does actually work, but the hook combination detected by Windows will be that of `!#s` since the alt modifier remains pressed, which will not initiate the search function.

See [remapping keys in AHK.](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm)